# Navigation Drawer not showing up

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

So I have an old application.
I wanted to add it a navigation drawer.
So I want the navigation drawer to work with my current activity and to show ONLY on the currecnt activity

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
```

So the main activity is a webView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<!--
      main content
 -->

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <WebView

        android:id="@+id/webView1"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:background="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!--
    navigation list item
-->
<FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/content_frame"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView

    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"

    android:layout_width="240dp"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_gravity="left"

    android:background="#2A323D"

    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So I expect my drawer to appear when I click the menu button or my webView detect the gesture left to right

```
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    drawerView = (View)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

AND

```
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I really don't know what am I missing, but **mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);** is not doing anything. 
There are no errors in the log.
The suppossed drawer does not show up, nothing happens.
I followed the [official](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout) guide and more online. No luck.

I don't want to use Fragments!

**UPDATE**

The issue is that in my 'onCreate' I have something like:`setContentView(webView);`

So if I remove it, my navigation drawer works!
BUT my webView does not. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Remove FrameLayout from your main_activity then try

Comment: The DrawerLayout should have two direct child views, the first for your main content and the second for the navigation drawer. In your case you have three, a Relative Layout, then a Frame Layout then a ListView. You don't seem to be using the Frame Layout for anything, so remove it, then you'll have two, like Drawer Layout expects.

Comment: Just did, same output: nothing happens.

Comment: The events are called and the instruction runs too, but nothing happens.
I'm running out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#2A323D"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Just copy and paste it

Answer (score 0):

Your onCreate() must have `setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);`
where drawer_layout is the xml which has a `DrawerLayout` as its root view

Follow the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) 
**Download** sample code and see which xml is passed to `setContentView()`

If you follow it carefully you will notice activity_main.xml contains Drawerlayout and not the main content's xml.

Also keep in mind that `DrawerLayout` must contain exactly two child `ViewGroup`s, where the first can be a fragment or FrameLayout that populates a fragment at runtime AND the second must be `NavigationView`

If you are still confused you can follow [this guide](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html) which has step-by-step instructions. Its worth a visit.